# How do i find the geographical co-ordinates/locations of a server?

Tags: mysql, networking, geography

I have a text file containing a list of 190 IP addresses. How do i get the location of all of these servers?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few free IP to Geo location apis out there such as [ipinfodb](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php), below the page there are some samples in different laguages. I suggest googling the term "ip to location api" for more apis.

Answer (score 1):

In python with pygeoip :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pygeoip

def main():
    db = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoLiteCity.dat')
    source = "MyIpList.txt"
    with open(source, 'r') as fs:
        lignes = fs.readlines()
        for ip in lignes:
            dico =  db.record_by_addr(ip)
            for k,v in dico.iteritems():
                print "%s : %s" % (k,v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You download [Geo city database](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz) and create MyIpList.txt file in this format.

```
64.233.161.99
209.131.36.159
```

This script print:
    country_code
    country_code3
    country_name
    region, city
    postal_code
    latitude
    longitude
    dma_code
    metro_code
    area_code
    region_name
    time_zone

[record_by_addr()](http://packages.python.org/pygeoip/pygeoip-pysrc.html#GeoIP.record_by_addr) return a dict.